Basic Auth for swagger docs in a Nest.js Fastify app
I am trying to protect the swagger docs alone using basic authentication.
I found this library ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fastify/basic-auth ). But I am not able to add authentication for that route alone.
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpAdapterHost, NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { FastifyReply, FastifyRequest } from 'fastify';
import qs from 'node:querystring';
import basicAuth from '@fastify/basic-auth';
import crypto from 'crypto';

async function bootstrap() {
const fastifyAdapter = new FastifyAdapter({logger: true});
fastifyAdapter.get('/', (req: FastifyRequest, res: FastifyReply) => {
    res.code(200);
    res.send({
      message: 'Hello Everyone',
    });
  });
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    fastifyAdapter
  );
  app.use(helmet());
  app.enableCors();
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  const authenticate = { realm: 'Westeros' };

  const validUsername = 'admin';
  const validPassword = 'admin';

  function compare(a, b) {
    a = Buffer.from(a);
    b = Buffer.from(b);
    if (a.length !== b.length) {
      // Delay return with cryptographically secure timing check.
      crypto.timingSafeEqual(a, a);
      return false;
    }

    return crypto.timingSafeEqual(a, b);
  }

  function validate(
    username,
    password,
    req: FastifyRequest,
    reply: FastifyReply,
    done
  ) {
    let result = true;
    result = compare(username, validUsername) && result;
    result = compare(password, validPassword) && result;
    if (result) {
      done();
    } else {
      reply.code(401);
    }
  }

  app.register(basicAuth, { validate, authenticate });

const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Healthis API')
    .setDescription('API documentation for Healthis')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addBearerAuth()
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api/docs', app, document);


app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
}

bootstrap();

I have tried to add this line to protect the swagger routes alone
app.use(['/api/docs', '/api/docs-json'], app.basicAuth);
But it is complaining with below error
Property 'basicAuth' does not exist on type 'NestFastifyApplication'.t
Even if I use any time, it does not work.
Expected result :

Please help.
